# Firebase's limitToLast() method not working as expected

Tags: java, android, firebase

I add a listener to an already populated Firebase node. I only want to get newly synced data. I call set limitToLast(1) on the ref, but it retrieves all of the data from the node. The code is set up to add listeners to multiple refs but currently it is only adding a listener to 1.

Here is my code:

```
                                    //size() == 1
for (int i  = 0; i < firebaseArrayList.size(); i++) { 
            firebaseArrayList.get(i).orderByValue().limitToLast(1);
            firebaseArrayList.get(i).addChildEventListener(this);
        }
```

Does anyone know why onChildAdded() is called for every item already in the node whilst I am using the query in my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/limittolast.html) it says:

```
Generates a new Query object limited to the last certain number of children.
```

In your code you are not using that object generated with `limitToLast`.

Here is the example in documentation:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("weight").limitToLast(2).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, that fixed the issue